# ASP.Net Core MVC Project cannot configure routes?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I recently started learning ASP.Net Core to develop a MVC Web API. But I cannot even get my hello world running.

In the `Startup.cs` I wrote:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRouting();
    services.AddMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            "default",
            "{version?}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

And the console says:

```
error CS1929: 'MvcOptions' does not contain a definition for 'MapRoute' and the best extension method overload 'MapRouteRouteBuilderExtensions.MapRoute(IRouteBuilder, string, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IRouteBuilder'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Routing You have to add in `Configure` method not `ConfigureService`. Try this sample.

Here add mvc to service

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddMvc();

    }
```

Here set routes

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```